# How to make md-tab not clickable?

Tags: html, angularjs

How do you make `md-tab` not clickable on angularJS? I do not want to disable the tab content, but just want to make the `md-tab` not clickable so users can't navigate through the pages by clicking on the tab:

This is my code:

```
<md-content class="md-padding" >
  <md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="" md-selected="selectedIndex">
      <md-tab label="one">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab One</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis ante augue. Phasellus volutpat neque ac dui mattis vulputate. Etiam consequat aliquam cursus. In sodales pretium ultrices. Maecenas lectus est, sollicitudin consectetur felis nec, feugiat ultricies mi.</p>
           <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="nextTab()">Next</md-button>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="two">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Two</h1>
          <p>Lorem  risus, pulvinar at interdum quis, vehicula sed odio. Phasellus in enim venenatis, iaculis tortor eu, bibendum ante. Donec ac tellus dictum neque volutpat blandit. Praesent efficitur faucibus risus, ac auctor purus porttitor vitae. Phasellus ornare dui nec orci posuere, nec luctus mauris semper.</p>

          <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="nextTab()">Next</md-button>
        </md-content>

      </md-tab>

    </md-tabs>
  </md-content>
```

Comment: you can prevent the default click action on your tabs using its `event` object, `$event.preventDefault();`

Comment: it doesn't work :(

Comment: are you referring to disabling the `next` button in every tab ? also can you create a plunker , http://plnkr.co

Comment: I also need answer for this one. Anyone here to solution this out.

Comment: Disable the tab...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Use `ng-disabled = "true"` on `<md-tab>` from the beginning and enable it when the user clicks on the next button.

Comment: It has to be ng-disabled

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation you have the example with the second tab disabled (not clickable): https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs.

```
     <md-tab id="tab2" ng-disabled="data.secondLocked">
        <md-tab-label>{{data.secondLabel}}</md-tab-label>
        <md-tab-body>
          ...
        </md-tab-body>
      </md-tab>
```

Comment: but will you be able to still navigate to the disabled tab programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Use `md-no-select-click` attribute on `md-tabs` to achieve the result.

Source: 
https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.4/api/directive/mdTabs

Answer (score 0):

use as

`<md-tab id="tab2" [disabled]="data.secondLocked">
        <md-tab-label>{{data.secondLabel}}</md-tab-label>
        <md-tab-body>
          ...
        </md-tab-body>
      </md-tab>`

for more info check https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/645

Answer (score 0):

You can do This in md-tabs

```
 md-selected="myTabIndex"
```

and in md-tab

```
ng-disabled="myTabIndex!==0" and Next
```